# How To Fix Type MutableRefObject Must Have A Symbol.Iterator Method Error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, casting

I'm using useRef to keep reference of a prop over renders during the lifetime of a component but I cannot seem to get past this type error:

```
Type 'MutableRefObject<any>' must have a 'symbol.iterator()' method that returns an iterator.
```

My code is:

```
const [values, setValues] = useRef<any[]>([])
```

Initially I was using an interface in place of any but changed to any while troubleshooting but still not working.
I have the empty array as the intial value. Not sure what I need to do here, please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`useRef` does not work like `useState`.  It doesn't return a value and an update callback.  It just returns a ref object (type `MutableRefObject`).

```
const valuesRef = useRef<any[]>([]);
```

When you write `const [values, setValues] = useRef<any[]>([])`, you are attempting to destructure the returned value from the hook into two variables `value` and `setValue`.  But you cannot destructure it because it is not an array (or an iterable).  Thus you get the error:

> Type 'MutableRefObject' must have a 'symbol.iterator()' method that returns an iterator.

You access the value of the ref through the `.current` property:

```
const values = valuesRef.current; // is type any[]
```

You update the values by setting the `.current` property:

```
valuesRef.current = [1, 2, 3];
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/mMyRzm)

[React Docs: useRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref)

Comment: ahh my bad, guess the left side needed to be just a variable like ...const values = useRef([]). I have only used it once before like this so totally messed up there. Thanks for the answer.